# Shell Script that parses multiple files and adds in a line if a condition is met?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I'm trying to write a shell script that reads over a hundred files containing multiple sections of parameters in each file, just to modify one line. If a section in one file does not contain `ELLIPSOID_CODE = 123`, add in line `ELLIPSOID_CODE = DEFAULT` before `OUTPUT_PARAMETER`. If a section in one file does contain `ELLIPSOID CODE = 123`, don't do anything. I am having trouble parsing in shell script to get this to work. I have an example of a file and my attempted code below.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------   ------
NUM_RUNS = 2 

INPUT_FILE = /home/autotest
OUTPUT_PROJECTION_TYPE = BLAH
ELLIPSOID_CODE = 123
OUTPUT_PARAMETER = BLAH
OUT_FILE = /home/autotest

INPUT_FILE = /home/autotest
OUTPUT_PROJECTION_TYPE = BLAH
OUTPUT_PARAMETER = BLAH
OUT_FILE = /home/autotest

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#Adds in the line "ELLIPSOID_CODE = DEFAULT" before OUTPUT_PARAMETER 

dir="/home/autotest/test/"
for i in "$dir"/*;
do
    sed -i 's:OUTPUT_PARAMETER:ELLIPSOID_CODE = DEFAULT\nOUTPUT_PARAMETER:' "$i";
done
```

My code adds in the `ELLIPSOID_CODE = DEFAULT` in every section no matter, when I just want it to add that line in in the second section of just this one file. Just to clarify I'm trying to get it to look like this:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
NUM_RUNS = 2 

INPUT_FILE = /home/autotest
OUTPUT_PROJECTION_TYPE = BLAH
ELLIPSOID_CODE = 123
OUTPUT_PARAMETER = BLAH
OUT_FILE = /home/autotest

INPUT_FILE = /home/autotest
OUTPUT_PROJECTION_TYPE = BLAH
ELLIPSOID_CODE = DEFAULT
OUTPUT_PARAMETER = BLAH
OUT_FILE = /home/autotest

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Is the order of parameters in each section guaranteed to be always the same (as in your example above) ?

Comment: Yes, it is. "ELLIPSOID_CODE = 123" would always be after "OUTPUT_PROJECTION_TYPE" if it appeared. And you would always insert "ELLIPSOID_CODE = DEFAULT" before OUTPUT_PARAMETER if "ELLIPSOID_CODE = 123" did not appear in that section.

Comment: In that case you've already got a working answer (though using `s` to insert lines is really ugly..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`sed`** solution:

```
sed -i '/^OUTPUT_PROJECTION_TYPE = .*/{ 
           N; s/OUTPUT_PARAMETER = .*/ELLIPSOID_CODE = DEFAULT\n&/; 
       }' /home/autotest/test/*
```

- `/^OUTPUT_PROJECTION_TYPE = .*/` - for each line started with pattern `OUTPUT_PROJECTION_TYPE = .*`(where `^` is regex anchor indicating the start of the string/line):

  - `N` - add a newline to the pattern space, then append the next line of input to the pattern space
  - `s/OUTPUT_PARAMETER = .*/ELLIPSOID_CODE = DEFAULT\n&/` - if the next line is `OUTPUT_PARAMETER = .*` (which means that `ELLIPSOID_CODE = ...` is missed) - prepend it with default line `ELLIPSOID_CODE = DEFAULT`. (`&` points to the whole matched string)

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Just for clarification if you had time, what is the purpose of the '^', 'N', '&', and the braces{}? Thanks again! @RomanPerekhrest

Comment: @dhboots,welcome, see my explanation

Answer (score 0):

First i found the line numbers for the pattern OUTPUT_PARAMETER. Then  assigned the variable j to  line number of pattern exists second time and then i replaced on line number as per requirement. Let me know for any doubts

command

```
j=`sed -n '/OUTPUT_PARAMETER/{;=;p}' filename|sed 'N;s/\n/ /g'| awk 'NR==2{print $1}' | sed -r "s/\s+//g" | sed '/^$/d'`


sed "`echo $j`s/OUTPUT_PARAMETER = BLAH/ELLIPSOID_CODE = DEFAULT\n&/g" filename
```

output

```
NUM_RUNS = 2

INPUT_FILE = /home/autotest
OUTPUT_PROJECTION_TYPE = BLAH
ELLIPSOID_CODE = 123
OUTPUT_PARAMETER = BLAH
OUT_FILE = /home/autotest

INPUT_FILE = /home/autotest
OUTPUT_PROJECTION_TYPE = BLAH
ELLIPSOID_CODE = DEFAULT
OUTPUT_PARAMETER = BLAH
OUT_FILE = /home/autotest
```